# N++ System Requirements on Mac

Tags: steam, macos, system-requirements, n++

I'm looking at N++ (https://store.steampowered.com/app/230270/N_NPLUSPLUS/) and it doesn't list the system requirements for a mac.

This question is not about whether my specific computer can run N++, but whether Macs in general can run it, and if so, what are the system requirements for those Macs which can run N++, since at the time of writing the Steam page for those is "(to be updated shortly!)".

Comment: While I don't know the exact specs, I would think even a mid-grade machine could run the game just fine given that N++ isn't exactly a demanding title.

Comment: True, but sometimes a game just won't have a build for a specific computer. It could be that it would run just fine, it's just that nobody has ever created the Mac-specific build and it may not exist. Everyone I know who plays it is on Windows.

Comment: Why not just use the Windows/Linux requirements for hardware? For software I doubt it would require much more than 10.13, but if you're running on the latest, then that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I don't have access to a windows or a linux right now so those don't apply.

Comment: It's not going to require wildly different specs for Mac when compared to Windows/Linux. Obviously any software requirements wouldn't apply, but the _hardware_ will probably be consistent across operating systems. That is user At0mic's point, I believe.

Comment: So as long as I have a decent setup it'll run on a mac?

Comment: Requirements still say "To be updated shortly" as of March 2024.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, N++ runs on Mac. Has done for a couple of years! Not sure of the specs but it is even in the process of being updated for Apple's new requirements. (you can use the localization beta branch if it doesn't work at the moment)